# Can't call a function from a contract, even though I'm transferring all the data correctly

Tags: web3.py, python

I Was trying to interact with a smart contract named https://etherscan.io/address/0x609c690e8f7d68a59885c9132e812eebdaaf0c9e
and use the function "swapAndBridge", I went ahead and matched the data types as they were described using python3 web3 package but I still get this error which shows I ve matched everything correctly.

```
def bridge_tokens(
    contract_address,
    sender_address,
    private_key,
    token,
    amount,
    recipient,
    destination_chain_id,
    receive_token,
    messenger,
    fee_token_amount
):
CONTRACT_ABI = [...]
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=CONTRACT_ABI)
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
gas_price = web3.eth.gas_price
data = contract.functions.swapAndBridge(
    token,
    amount,
    recipient,
    destination_chain_id,
    receive_token,
    1,
    messenger,
    fee_token_amount
).buildTransaction({
    'gas': 310000,
    'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gas_price, 'ether'),
    'nonce': nonce,
})

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(data, private_key)

txn_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(txn_hash)
```

Error message:
Could not identify the intended function with name `swapAndBridge`, positional arguments with type(s) `bytes,int,bytes,int,bytes,int,int,int` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `swapAndBridge`: ['swapAndBridge(bytes32,uint256,bytes32,uint256,bytes32,uint256,uint8,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.

as shown above all my data types match the ones that are required

thanks for your time and help.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing your code and full traceback.

Comment: It's probably something with your arguments as the error says, but difficult to tell.

Comment: paste your python code

Comment: Add my python code.Thanks for help